# Auto-update apps in ionic1

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play-console

I have submitted the version 0.0.2 ( update for 0.0.1 ) of the application to Play Store.

If there is auto-update , Do I need to something so that app automatically gets updated on the devices it is installed.

Comment: check this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/code-push/
this plugin is for ionic 3+ versions.

Comment: i am working on ionicV1 . so i do need plugins for ionic1